# Metallic and Smoothness Map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have a metallic and smoothness map. The metallic is in the red channel, the smoothness is in the alpha channel. (This map is used in a Unity 3D project, by the Standard shader).

The values in the map are as so:

```
A: 0 - Not smooth; 255 - Smooth
R: 0 - Not metallic; 255 - Metallic
```

I have the metallic value working now I believe.

I need to invert the alpha (smoothness) channel somehow as the 'Principled BSDF' shader expects roughness. What is the best way to do this?

Here is my node setup:

[image]

Comment: Cycles has some weird behaviors when textures have unrelated data in the alpha channel, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32450/how-to-separate-texture-alpha-without-premultiplying-the-color?rq=1 Otherwise, your setup sounds correct from the description given.

Comment: @JtheNinja Yes, it seems the metallic setup was correct. The smoothness in the alpha channel needs inverting now somehow.

Comment: Inverting a value in the range of 0-1 is as simple as subtracting it from 1.  Use a math node on subtract mode.  (After you check out JtheNinja's link.)

Comment: You are right! I was trying to subtract 255. If you write this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.