# TGA texture shows up black in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

Basically

Here's material preview after I plug in the alpha channel map into anything really
[image: here's material preview]

And here's what it looks like in render

[image]

I am confusion

I know blender used to have issues with TGA textures but I thought it was fixed? As I understand, it combines all the channels together, and usually, plugging alpha channel into something leaves rgb channels looking like they should, but not here and idk why ‍♀️
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to *Image Editor* to see texture, Alpha channel separates only red part of your texture.

[image]

You would have to change *Alpha* channel or set **None** in *Node* or *Image Properties*.

Render View
[image]